# Difference between "up to interpretation" and "up for interpretation"

Tags: meaning

I was reading [this](https://www.nyfa.org/ask-artisthotline-am-i-an-emerging-artist-143960095478) article and I came across the following sentence:

> An emerging artist is usually defined as someone at the early stages
> of their career. Maybe, as an “emerging” artist, you're honing your
> style and have landed some recognition from a critic, but you don't
> have commercial representation yet. ... The word “mid-career” is also
> **up to interpretation**.

In my search for the meaning of *up to interpretation* I also found **up for interpretation** which in turn led me on a search for the difference between **up to** and **up for** but that does not seem to help.
I am still not sure about the difference in meaning between *up to interpretation* and *up for interpretation* (if there is any).

Comment: Sounds like sort of typo. *up for interpretation* is correct and I don't know how *up to* makes sense.

Comment: @iBug In my search, I found many examples for "up to interpretarion" (actually more than ones for "up for interpretation") like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLFhKCgexRU) video at around 13:10 for example.

Comment: @iBug sorry at around 13:00.

Comment: From the context it sounds like it should be "open to interpretation".

Answer (score 1):

The word “mid-career” is also up **to** interpretation.

**That means it depends on interpretation**

whereas:
The word “mid-career” is also up **for** interpretation.

**That means that it  has been designated for interpretation or to be interpreted.**

Answer (score -1):

lets look at it this way... if @iBug is correct about the typo then we have nothing to discuss...
but we have two ways of somethings as it comes to the collocation for **Up**

we have:

1. *We are up to sth*... means we have decided to do sth or we are about to do sth (sth = something) Example: I know you are up to something == (I know you have something in mind and you want to do it)
2. *we are up for sth*... means we are eager to do something... can be a decision made before and now we are showing our passion to do it. Example : I am up for camping == (I stand with those who want to camp)

hope I could be clear

Comment: The question is *sth. be up to*, not *sb. be up to*. Whether the subject is person or object makes quite a difference here.

Comment: @iBug Sorry I dont get you...
I explained the difference between Up to and Up for. and at the beginning of the sentence we have a subject called ?? " an emerging artist".
and the question was the exact difference between "up to" and "up for"

Comment: The question asked for *the word “mid-career” is also up to interpretation* where the subject is *the word*. Can you explain how the meanings you posed apply to non-person subjects?

Comment: @iBug
the question of the @-Mohammad is the difference 
and the article that stated "mid-career" refers to something that is not stated in the current article due to the shortage of it.. and i went to read the whole idea, I this context i think it means there are different interpretations of it